# Tag [windows-phone-7.5] should be a synonym for [windows-phone-7.1] not [windows-phone-7]!

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Currently on SO [windows-phone-7.5](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.5) is a synonym for [windows-phone-7](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7).

However [windows-phone-7.5](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.5) and [windows-phone-7.1](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.1) should be synonyms. Because 7.1 is the technical version, and 7.5 is the marketing version. **This is the same things!**

7.1's wiki confirms that:

> The codename "Mango" update to Windows Phone 7. Made available to developers in June 2011 and scheduled for public availability later in 2011. It contains over 500 new features and 1500+ new APIs. This tag can be considered a synonym of [windows-phone-7.5] as they both refer to the same thing. ...

We need to fix that, because current state is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Version specific tags are a necessity in some cases.  I have no knowledge in development for [windows-phone](/questions/tagged/windows-phone) so I can only speculate on the differences.

Sometimes there are **major** changes in versions of technologies.  New methods are created and old ones are deprecated.  The version specific tags assist users to understand the exact systems that the OP is using.  Older versions might have limitations and newer versions might have different requirements.

The decision to merge/create synonyms or assign new synonyms should be left to someone who has enough knowledge to know the exact details of the changes between versions - most likely one of the [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-phone-7/topusers) for the [windows-phone-7](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7) tag.

Comment: I know what I'm talking about. WP7 questions are general questions. WP7.1 and WP7.5 are version specific. And 7.5 **is the same thing as** 7.1 And current state doesn't represent that.

Comment: I have no doubt =).  my post was meant to contrast the other answer which disregarded version specific tags altogether...

Comment: Explanation? Someone? Fine.. I'll just go sulk in the Tavern :(

Comment: explanation - to me your answer looks too generic for this particular case. It lacks specifics, lacks _knowledge to know the exact details_

Comment: @gna - thank you for your clarification.