# Unable to propose a synonym, where it references a deleted tag

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

I was trying to propose [windows-phone-7.1](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.1) as a synonym of [windows-phone-7](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7) (on the rationale that [windows-phone-7.5](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.5) is [a synonym already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129607/130044)) But it gives error:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> Reverse synonym windows-phone-7.1 already proposed on the tag windows-phone-mango

However, If I try to propose [windows-phone-mango](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-mango) it tells me the tag doesn't exist.

Comment: The tag does exist, as a synonym, try it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-mango ...the error message definitely needs love, but the creation of a synonym to a synonym should not be allowed...checking with waffles on the behavior here.

Comment: @NickCraver, I read it that he was trying to make 7.1 (a tag) into a synonym of 7 (another tag).   This should be allowed.

Comment: @BrockAdams - mango points to that 7.1...if that tag points to something else, we start creating synonym redirect chains, not good.

Comment: @NickCraver, So no tags can be made synonyms if they have synonyms of their own?!?!  This hasn't come up before? ... Shouldn't the system redirect any synonyms of the subordinated tag to the new master?  It appears that 7.1 and 7.5 are the same thing.  If one is a synonym for 7, the other should be too.  In this case, maybe "Mango" should be rewritten to a synonym for 7.

Comment: @BrockAdams - I don't disagree *something* is wrong here...that's why I pinged Sam on it, not 100% sure what the behavior is *supposed* to be here, but we can't have an infinite synonym depth tree, nothing is supported there...for example synonyms of synonyms don't show up on the synonym list of a tag (but would redirect there).  There's no built-in recursive behavior for this I'm aware of (nor do I think there should be...if there's a shift then both tags should probably point directly to the new master, for example).

Comment: To complicate things a bit, I'm not sure if this proposal should be approved, so I'm reluctant to change it (being a mod, auto-approve, etc)...from the discussion it appears 7.5 (marketing) = 7.1 (software), but they're *not* equivalent to 7.0

Comment: @NickCraver But 7.5 has already been flagged as = 7.0 - is there anyway to undo that **and** allow 7.5 to point to that instead?

Comment: @RowlandShaw - allow 7.5 to point to what? 7.1? lots of tags flying around here :)

Comment: @NickCraver I was going to try to make it point to 7.0 (to match 7.5); but it would be arguably better to re-point 7.5 to 7.1; per the linked post

Comment: Same issue with [tfs-build] and [team-build]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168859/tag-synonym-issue-with-tfsbuild-and-team-build