# Tag synonym issue with [tfsbuild] and [team-build]

Tags: bug

The tags [tfsbuild](/questions/tagged/tfsbuild) and [team-build](/questions/tagged/team-build) are actually the same, but when trying to suggest a merge I get an error that [team-build](/questions/tagged/team-build) is proposed to be merged with [teambuild](/questions/tagged/teambuild). Trying to suggest [teambuild](/questions/tagged/teambuild) as a synonym for [tfsbuild](/questions/tagged/tfsbuild) results in the error that [teambuild](/questions/tagged/teambuild) doesn't exist :S.